# Bing maps Pushpins from XML Feed

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, windows-phone-7

Ive been using this tutorial to try and display pushpins on a map:
http://compiledexperience.com/windows-phone-7/tutorials/quake

Im almost there wit hthe help you you guys below, but

If I replace my bits with the original bits (commented out parts)
and then do 'Start debugging', I get an unhandled exception. If I continue debugging I see the map and the pushpins for a split second and then it quits out.
I put back the original commented code and its fine...
Let me know if you need anymore info. Im so frustrated at this :( Thanks once again.

Callstack:

> QuakeML.dll!QuakeML.App.OnUnhandledException(object sender = {QuakeML.App}, System.Windows.ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e = {System.Windows.ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs}) Line 37 + 0x5 bytes  C#
>       System.Windows.dll!MS.Internal.Error.CallApplicationUEHandler(System.Exception e = {"UIElement.Arrange(finalRect) cannot be called with Infinite or NaN values in finalRect. "}) + 0x30 bytes
>       System.Windows.dll!MS.Internal.Error.CallAUEHandler(uint hr = 2148474880, out uint bIsHandled = 0) + 0x6 bytes
>       [Native to Managed Transition]

Current code:

```
namespace QuakeML
{
    public partial class MainPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Loaded += OnLoaded;
        }

        private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            LoadQuakes();
        }

        private void LoadQuakes()
        {
            var webClient = new WebClient();

            webClient.OpenReadCompleted += OnOpenReadCompleted;


            var uri = "http://www.tfl.gov.uk/tfl/businessandpartners/syndication/feed.aspx?email=mycomputer@clara.co.uk&feedId=3";
          //  var uri = "http://magma.geonet.org.nz/services/quake/quakeml/1.0.1/query?startDate=2010-09-03&endDate=2010-09-05&magnitudeLower={0:0.0}&magnitudeUpper=8";

            webClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(uri, UriKind.Absolute));
        }



        private void OnOpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            var document = XDocument.Load(e.Result);

             if(document.Root == null)
                return;

             var xmlns = XNamespace.Get("http://www.tfl.gov.uk/tfl/syndication/namespaces/geo");
             //var xmlns = XNamespace.Get("http://quakeml.org/xmlns/quakeml/1.0");

                var events = from ev in document.Descendants("item")
                         select new
                         {
                             Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(ev.Element(xmlns + "Point").Element(xmlns + "lat").Value),
                             Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(ev.Element(xmlns + "Point").Element(xmlns + "long").Value),
                         };


              //var events = from ev in document.Descendants(xmlns + "event")
                //           select new
               //            {
                //              Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(ev.Element(xmlns + "origin").Element(xmlns + "latitude").Element(xmlns + "value").Value),
               //               Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(ev.Element(xmlns + "origin").Element(xmlns + "longitude").Element(xmlns + "value").Value),

               //           };

            QuakeLayer.Children.Clear();


                foreach(var ev in events)
            {
                var accentBrush = (Brush)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"];

                var pin = new Pushpin
                {
                    Location = new GeoCoordinate
                    {
                        Latitude = ev.Latitude,
                        Longitude = ev.Longitude
                    },
                    Background = accentBrush,

                };

                QuakeLayer.AddChild(pin, pin.Location);
            }
        }

        private void OnRefresh(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            LoadQuakes();
        }

    }
}
```

Map item on mainpage:

Comment: Which lines in the above code is line 37?

Comment: PS: line 37 which is in app.xaml.cs line: Debugger.Break(); in:

private static void OnUnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) { if(Debugger.IsAttached) Debugger.Break(); }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the namespace reference as it's aliased in the XML you're parsing.

This works:

```
var xmlns = XNamespace.Get("http://www.tfl.gov.uk/tfl/syndication/namespaces/geo");

var events = from ev in document.Root.Descendants("item")
                select new
                        {
                            Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(ev.Element(xmlns + "Point").Element(xmlns + "lat").Value),
                            Longitude = Convert.ToDouble(ev.Element(xmlns + "Point").Element(xmlns + "long").Value),
                        };
```

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you specified the line on which you get the exception but I'm going to guess its a problem with the way you are using `XName`s.

Where you are using "geo:Point", "geo:lat" and "geo:long" you should first create these variables:-

```
XName geoPoint = XName.Get("Point", "http://www.tfl.gov.uk/tfl/syndication/namespaces/geo");
XName geoLat = XName.Get("lat", "http://www.tfl.gov.uk/tfl/syndication/namespaces/geo");
XName geoLong = XName.Get("long", "http://www.tfl.gov.uk/tfl/syndication/namespaces/geo");
```

Then your code can look like:-

```
var events = from ev in document.Root.Descendants("item")   
             select new   
             {   
                Latitude = (double)ev.Element(geoPoint).Element(geoLat),   
                Longitude = (double)ev.Element(geoPoint).Element(geoLong)   
             };
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i am trying to get your solution working. The error I get when runnning (seems like its trying to load the feed as its already loaded the map) XmLException was unhandled The ':' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, cannot be included in a name.

This is on line 57

Comment: @Dan: That is the exception I would expect you to get when you were using those "geo:xxxx" strings.  Its unclear to me whether you mean you are still getting that with my modifications?

Comment: Altrtered original post for current situation. Thanks. Dan

Comment: I am wondering if there are too many pushpins, there are only 182.
I will try and recreate the app in a silverlight desktop app tonight and see if this works.

Comment: @Dan: You really, really need to find out which specific line in your code is actually throwing the error.  Put a break point at the top of the OnOpenReadCompleted and single step through it.  Make sure you have applied the changes that I have given you, if it still fails adjust your question to include those changes as you have made them.  Debugging is about being specific and methodical.

Comment: Hi Anthony, thanks for your advice once again, I will try this and report back my findings.

Comment: Hi, ive tried to do some debugging and this is what I have found. I am using the code written in the first post. I placed breakpoints at several bits and stepped through. The last two breakpoints were at: var pin = new Pushpin and: QuakeLayer.AddChild(pin, pin.Location);. It went back and forth these two items 182 times (thats how many items there are in the feed) and then bombed out. I hope this gives some idea. Many thanks.

Comment: Ive edited the xml files and hosted on my own server. It now works but the limit is 143 pushpins in the xml file. Any more than that and it has the unhandled exception!!!